# jquery ui autocomplete in zend form

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, zendx, zend-framework

I have JSON data returned in my action controller:

```
$results = $repo->getMatchingCityName($searchTerm);
```

Response that i'm getting:

```
[{"CityName":"Montreal"},{"CityName":"New york"}]........
```

But jquery ui autocomplete doesn't show anything

tried

```
$this->_helper->json(array_values($results));
```

and

```
Zend_Json::encode($results);
```

But no use. How do I convert into

```
[{"value":"Montreal","label":"Montreal"},{"value":"New york","label":"New york"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working like this

```
$temp = array();
foreach($results as $row)
{
    $value = $row["CityName"];
    array_push($temp, array(
        "label" => $value,
        "value" => $value
    ));
}

$data = $this->_helper->json($temp);
$this->_helper->autoComplete($data);
```

Added the view helper in bootstrap

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
    new ZendX_JQuery_Controller_Action_Helper_AutoComplete()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$results = $repo->getMatchingCityName($searchTerm); // [{"CityName":"Montreal"},{"CityName":"New york"}]........


$data = Zend_Json::decode($results);

$new = array();

foreach ($data as $row) {
   $temp['value'] = $row['CityName'];
   $temp['label'] = $row['CityName'];
   array_push($new, $temp);
}

$newEncode = Zend_Json::decode($new); //[{"value":"Montreal","label":"Montreal"},{"value":"New york","label":"New york"}]
```